# Why putting if condition inside first bracket doesnot work while using ternary operator?

Tags: javascript

`if` condition inside first bracket causes error:

```js
function fd(t) {
  let output = '';
  if (t >= 41) {
    let mns = 45
    (mns === 1) ? (output = "true") : (output = "false");
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(fd(65));
```

> Error message: "ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `mns'
>   before initialization"

`if` condition without first bracket works just fine:

```js
function fd(t) {
  let output = '';
  if (t >= 41) {
    let mns = 45
    mns === 1 ? (output = "true") : (output = "false");
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(fd(65));
```

Can anyone please explain me this behavior?

Comment: semicolons are your friend

Comment: By the way: use just `output = String(mns === 1);` instead of the conditional. Or just skip the stringification and return a Boolean to begin with, with `output = mns === 1;`.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a semicolon after `let mns = 45` to conclude the statement. Without the semicolon to conclude the statement, it would be like trying to pass `(mns === 1)` as an argument to the `let` statement. It would be like the two lines were combined into one: `let mns = 45(mns === 1) ? (output = "true") : (output = "false");`

The second function works because there is no bracket around `msn === 1`, so it won't try to pass it as an argument to the `let` statement.

As a general rule, always remember to add a semicolon after **each** JavaScript statement.

```js
function fd(t) {
  let output = '';
  if (t >= 41) {
    let mns = 45;
    (mns === 1) ? (output = "true") : (output = "false");
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(fd(65));
```

As Xufox suggested in the comments, you could just move the ternary operator to the return statement to avoid ambiguity.

```js
function fd(t) {
     let mns;
      if (t >= 41) {
        mns = 45;
      }
      return (mns === 1) ? ("true") : ("false");
}

console.log(fd(65));
```

Comment: the why second function works?

Comment: It’s not trying to pass `(mns === 1) ? (output = "true") : (output = "false")` as an argument, only `mns === 1`. The entire statement would read `let mns = 45(mns === 1) ? (output = "true") : (output = "false");`.

Comment: @noobie Because there's no bracket.

Comment: @noobie Because that one is _unambiguous_ in terms of [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/4642212).

Comment: @Xufox I have edited my answer.

Comment: @hev1 Oh, the alternative line to the conditional was actually meant to be directed towards the OP, not you.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because `let` declaration is not concluded yet. To end the declaration use `;` or declare as `var` instead of let.

```js
function fd(t) {
  let output = '';
  if (t >= 41) {
    let mns = 45;  // note the semicolan or declare it as var
    (mns === 1) ? (output = "true") : (output = "false");
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(fd(65));
```